# ¿Como puedo personalizar mi aplicacion de xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo eliminar el nombre, de la aplicación de este lugar, muchas gracias por su ayuda...

Comment: Solo debes editar en tu XAML el titulo de tu layout

Answer (score 1):

El titulo de la pagina actual se puede cambiar en la propiedad **Title** , asi como el icono (propiedad Icon) asociado.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   x:Class="Demo.MainPage"
   Title="Titulo de tu Preferencia" Icon="DefaultIcon.png">
```

De igual forma, recomiendo cambiar el **nombre de la aplicación** (Application Name), puedes acceder a traves de las propiedades del proyecto. 
[image: Propiedades]

[image: Resultado]